# How to change position of nodes vertically in Sankey Diagram

Tags: r, position, nodes, sankey-diagram

How can I change position of the nodes in a Sankey Diagram vertically (y axis) to get them in the middle / central to the previous node and not at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
  var options = {
  width: 900,
  sankey: { node: { nodePadding: 80 } },
};
```